# How to log the number of active DB Connections using ibatis?

Tags: java, ibatis

I am using ibatis in my application to manage the connections to the oracle database and I am trying to update the maximum number of DB connections as these values were not modified from the time these were originally set.

I have checked the database table v$session for the current number of active sessions, but this value alone will not help me reconfigure my ibatis settings.

I am trying for a way print the number of active connections in use into the logs so that I can parse them to get the usage statistics of my application and then update my configurations.

Comment: This is a function of your connection pool and not ibatis.

Comment: My ibatis config is using <dataSource type="SIMPLE"> and calls are being made to the DB using the SqlMapClient . I am unable to find any ibatis related API to print the number of active connections,